# "Much depends on the guilt or innocence…" is 'much' the subject of the sentence?

Tags: ellipsis, syntax, subjects

> **Much** depends on the guilt or innocence of these archetypal “innocents”-- --the first in a long line of allegedly framed leftists from Alger Hiss to the Rosenbergs to Leonard Peltier to Mumia Abu Jamal--including the very credibility of the American cultural establishment. (*[Source](http://www.cashill.com/intellect_fraud/sacco_and_vanzetti.htm)*)

Is the subject of this sentence really "much"? I tend to add "it" in the position of the subject ("It much depends…"). Was it simply omitted or is the pronoun not proper?

Comment: *Much* is the subject, equivalent to *a great deal* or *many things*.

Comment: And the sentence with "it" (It much depends…) would be ungrammatical or would have a different meaning?

Comment: Yes. Your *it* has no referent, which would ordinarily be a fused relative clause such as "It much depends on X whether Y or Z" or "It much depends on X what Y we choose", and so forth.

Comment: OK. Thank you. In your examples of a fused relative clause the referent of "it" is the subordinate clause, i.e. "what Y we choose…"?

Comment: Yes. This construction is called an [*it-cleft*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleft_sentence); it is typically used to promote an object or other subordinate constituent into the predicate ("new information") position.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting link. This looks like a great answer; it would be a pity to leave this question unanswered...

Comment: https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=much from http://www.onelook.com/?w=much&ls=a